# Special function on feature maps of convolutional layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

## In Short:

How do I pass feature maps from convolutional layer defined in Keras to a special function (region proposer) which is then passed to other Keras layers (e.g Softmax classifier)?

## Long:

I'm trying to implement something like [Fast R-CNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn) (**not** Faster R-CNN) in Keras. The reason for this is because I'm trying to implement a custom architecture as seen in the figure below:

[image: from "TextMaps" by Tom Gogar]

Here's the code for the figure above (excluding candidates input):

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, concatenate
from keras.activations import relu, sigmoid, linear
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform, Constant, TruncatedNormal, RandomNormal, Zeros

#  Network 1, Layer 1
screenshot = Input(shape=(1280, 1280, 0),
                   dtype='float32',
                   name='screenshot')
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96,
               kernel_size=11,
               strides=(4, 4),
               activation=relu,
               padding='same')(screenshot)
pooling1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3),
                        strides=(2, 2),
                        padding='same')(conv1)
normalized1 = BatchNormalization()(pooling1)  # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145768/importance-of-local-response-normalization-in-cnn

# Network 1, Layer 2

conv2 = Conv2D(filters=256,
               kernel_size=5,
               activation=relu,
               padding='same')(normalized1)
normalized2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384,
               kernel_size=3,
               activation=relu,
               padding='same',
               kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),
               bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(normalized2)

# Network 2, Layer 1

textmaps = Input(shape=(160, 160, 128),
                 dtype='float32',
                 name='textmaps')
txt_conv1 = Conv2D(filters=48,
                   kernel_size=1,
                   activation=relu,
                   padding='same',
                   kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),
                   bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(textmaps)

# (Network 1 + Network 2), Layer 1

merged = concatenate([conv3, txt_conv1], axis=-1)
merged_padding = ZeroPadding2D(padding=2, data_format=None)(merged)
merged_conv = Conv2D(filters=96,
                     kernel_size=5,
                     activation=relu, padding='same',
                     kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),
                     bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(merged_padding)
```

As seen above, final step of the network that I'm trying to build is **ROI Pooling**, which is done this way in R-CNN:

[image: from main publication of Fast R-CNN on Arxiv]

Now [there is a code for ROI Pooling layer in Keras](https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN/blob/master/keras_frcnn/RoiPoolingConv.py), but to that layer I need to pass **region proposals**. As you may already know, region proposals are usually done by the algorithm known as Selective Search, [which is already implemented in the Python](https://github.com/AlpacaDB/selectivesearch).

---

## Problem:

Selective Search can easily pick up a normal image and give us region proposals like this:

[image: from selective search Github page]

Now **the problem** is, that instead of image I should pass a feature map, from the layer `merged_conv1` as seen in the code above:

```
merged_conv = Conv2D(filters=96,
                     kernel_size=5,
                     activation=relu, padding='same',
                     kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),
                     bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(merged_padding)
```

The layer above is nothing but a reference to shape, so obviously it wont work with selectivesearch:

```
>>> import selectivesearch
>>> selectivesearch.selective_search(merged_conv, scale=500, sigma=0.9, min_size=10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/somepath/selectivesearch.py", line 262, in selective_search
    assert im_orig.shape[2] == 3, "3ch image is expected"
AssertionError: 3ch image is expected
```

I guess I should do:

```
from keras import Model
import numpy as np
import cv2
import selectivesearch
img = cv2.imread('someimage.jpg')
img = img.reshape(-1, 1280, 1280, 3)
textmaps = np.ones(-1, 164, 164, 128)  # Just for example
model = Model(inputs=[screenshot, textmaps], outputs=merged_conv)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
feature_maps = np.reshape(model.predict([img, textmaps]), (96, 164, 164))
feature_map_1 = feature_maps[0][0]
img_lbl, regions = selectivesearch.selective_search(feature_map_1, scale=500, sigma=0.9, min_size=10)
```

But then what If I want to add let's say softmax classifier which accepts "regions" variable? (btw I am aware that there are few problems with selective search taking anything other than input of channel 3, but this is not relevant to the question)

## Question:

Region proposal (using selective search) is an important part the neural network, how can I modify it so that it takes feature maps (activations) from convolutional layer `merged_conv`?

Maybe I should create my own Keras layer?

Comment: You can try modifying `selectivesearch` file as per the dims of your feature map. It was written for `3` channel input image. Adapting this, you easily pass it through `roi-pooling`.

Comment: @AnkishBansal Thank you for the response. Yes, that is a second problem. In fact, I'm not aware whether or not the feature map was extracted properly - you can see it in my last code block where I take one single feature map as example. Should I take each feature map (with shape `(164, 164)`) and pass it to `selectivesearch`? Or should I modify `selectivesearch` so that it accepts full input of shape `(164, 164, 96)` channels? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best understanding, `selective-search` take an input and return `n` no of patches of different `(H,W)`. So in your case, `feature-map` is of dims `(164,164,96)`, you can assume `(164,164)` as the input for selective-search and it will give you `n` number of patch, for exp as `(H1,W1), (H2,W2),...`. So you can now append all the `channel` as it is, to that patch, so it becomes as of dims `(H1,W1,96),(H2,W2,96),....`.

Note: But there is downside of doing this too. `Selective-Search` algorithm use the strategy in which it breaks the image in grids and then re-join those patch as per the heatmap of the object. You would not be able to do that on feature-map. But you can use random search method on that and it can be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was not quite able to understand the post. Will `selective-search` work on feature map? Or it will just not be able to do specific part of `selective-search` algorithm (rejoining patches by a heatmap of the object).

Comment: I am not sure that `selective-serach` will work perfectly fine on feature map.  Let's understand the selective-search first, how it works.

Comment: The way selective-search algorithm work is that it divide the image in grid and use some way to combine them to have useful patch. For example in the above image you posted, you can see that if search algo give us a patch containing only eye, that will not be useful having only the eye. So it combine those patch to have an face in that patch, that will be useful patch for further processing. More you can read it here http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf

Comment: Well that's interesting. I guess I'll still use `selectivesearch` considering the fact that this question regards the other matter. But are you aware of anything else that might be better for feature maps?

Comment: I don't recall any. Actually this way, it become `Faster-RCNN`, where we extract regions on top of the feature map, whereas in `Fast-RCNN`, we use different conv net to extract features for each region. But let not to worry about it, and give it a try.

Comment: I have been trying `Faster-RCNN`, but I found out that it can't work since it creates a loophole. As you may already know, they use region proposal networks that requires separate training, but if my base network is untrained, then [there is a loophole](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/44526/47359). I guess modification of selective search is the only way. Thank you for the help

Comment: Making an update. Actually, the data was gathered from websites, so that we only take bounding boxes of specific DOM elements which are then projected onto the feature map of convolution of last concatenated shape in the figure, and then they are maxpooled. Unfortunately, this can't be done with Keras (but can be done with Caffe), since we are not aware of exact number of proposals, and Keras has a weird architecture that doesn't really support any of this...